# How can I copy the entire _site folder from my Jekyll Blog Site to a Blog folder of my main Website hosted in Linux

Tags: web, jekyll, blogs, static-site

I have my website with HTML/CSS/JS/PHP files hosted on a Godaddy Shared VPS with cpanel. 
Now I have created a Jekyll Blog Site on my local machine (Mac OS X). I want to copy the entire contents of this blog (_site folder?) to the subfolder called 'blog' in my website called '_public_html/blog'.

Is this doable? If not, what is a recommended approach to export my blog site to my main website blog folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... that is exactly how this should work. Use FTP to move the content of the _site folder to your public_html folder on your server and you have 'deployed' your website.

More user-friendly alternatives are using platforms like CloudCannon, Forestry.io and Netlify.